# How do I Save JSON API response in different javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Working on API response that gets user data from 10K ft system via API. The response looks like:

```js
"data": [{
    "id": 30000,
    "display_name": "John Doe",
    "email": "Johndoes@testmail.com",
  },
```

I want to save this data in three different arrays for each response to be used later for looping through user id. I am not sure how to go about it. Below is the code I have worked on so far. I will appreciate any help here. Thanks

```js
    function getUsers() {
      var auth = 'authentication'
      var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users?' + '&auth=' + auth;
      var options = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth
        }
      };

            };
           let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
           let json = JSON.parse(response);
               };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    var ids = [];
    var display_names = [];
    var emails = [];

    function result(data) {

    data.forEach(element => {
                 ids.push(element.id);
    display_names.push(element.display_name);
    emails.push(element.email);
  });

  return { "ids": ids, "display-names": display_names, "emails": emails };
}

console.log(result(data));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand...Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
    let json = JSON.parse(response);
    let ids = [];
    let dis_name = [];
    let email = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        ids.push(json[i].id);
        dis_name.push(json[i].display_name);
        email.push(json[i].email);
    }
```

P.S Consider using **let** keyword instead of var.

Comment: hey Nicolas, thanks for looking at my code. You are right and have interpreted my question correctly. I have edited my question with the current code from your recommendation. I am running this in google app script console and after using **let** as per your suggestion it  throws an error **Missing ; before statement**. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Yeap I've made a mistake at the beginning of the for loop. Just updated my code.  Just copy the code again and everything should be fine. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Have copied the code, but still have the same error, it comes from the line just before **var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);**. I however changed **let** to **var** and the execution was successful. Not sure why I can run it with **let**

Comment: Glad I was able to help mate. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

if "data" contains more objects you need to loop through the data array and push the ids, display_names and emails in separate arrays. The below example will help you.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "id": 30000,
        "display_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "Johndoes@testmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 30001,
        "display_name": "John Cena",
        "email": "JohnCens@testmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 30002,
        "display_name": "John kabaraya",
        "email": "Johnkabarayas@testmail.com"
    }
]

var ids = [];
var display_names = [];
var emails = [];

function result(data) {

    data.forEach(element => {
        ids.push(element.id);
        display_names.push(element.display_name);
        emails.push(element.email);
    });

    return { "ids": ids, "display-names": display_names, "emails": emails };
}

console.log(result(data));
```

Comment: Hey, @Sachintha thanks for looking at my code. I have modified my question to incorporated your recommendation but I ran into a syntax error. I have included a screenshot of the same. The error is basically at the **data.forEach(element => {** Kindly look at it and advice

Comment: I'm refering "data" to your response. I advice you to don't copy the given code as it is . you should pass the response to the "result" fumction.